# Plotting values from multiple columns but for one row

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dataframe

I have data for a single row and multiple columns.I would like to **plot the data for each column in a single plot**.I have 100 columns like this.What would be the best way to do this in R.

```
matplot(df[1,],type="o")
```

I have tried various options such as above for the below data:

```
  gene  Sample_23770_A54T_RNAX  Sample_27931_RNAX   Sample_28891_RNAX   Sample_28897_RNAX Sample_28977_RNAX Sample_28979_RNAX   Sample_PM100_Z1_1_RNA   Sample_PM117_Z10_1_Case_RNASeq Sample_PM117_Z1_1_Case_RNASeq
  CD274 5.9315  1.9569  10.3786 5.2705  5.7112  1.814   0.3493  0.6846  1.0373
```

Also,Can I use ggplot function for multiple columns?Basically,I want to plot the expression value for the single row comparing between 100 different columns .

Comment: If you can, reshape your data with the `melt()` function to have your rows as columns.

Comment: from question "plot the data for each column in a single plot"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
cd274 <- read.table(text = "gene  Sample_23770_A54T_RNAX  Sample_27931_RNAX   Sample_28891_RNAX   Sample_28897_RNAX Sample_28977_RNAX Sample_28979_RNAX   Sample_PM100_Z1_1_RNA   Sample_PM117_Z10_1_Case_RNASeq Sample_PM117_Z1_1_Case_RNASeq
CD274 5.9315  1.9569  10.3786 5.2705  5.7112  1.814   0.3493  0.6846  1.0373", header = T)
cd274 <- melt(cd274[, 2:ncol(cd274)])
ggplot(cd274, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()
```